# iPython nbconvert not working with headings

Tags: windows, command-line, pdf-generation, jupyter-notebook, pdflatex

### Question:

How can I convert ipynb files to PDF if they have headings? I can't make it with the normal command.

### Why I ask so:

I've been searching info for many days to get over this problem but I resign and ask it in here. I'm running iPython notebook (with python 3.4) on Windows 8.1 and when I use the command:

```
ipython nbconvert my file.ipynb --to latex --post PDF
```

to convert my notebooks to pdf it only works when my file has **no headings**. If I have the same file and I don't write any heading it works smoothly but the problem comes when I have to put one. It can't even convert the notebook to anything (not HTML, not just LaTeX format...).
My LaTeX distribution is working fine, I can make .tex documents with headings and so on... but the trouble is when I use the nbconvert to make PDF files with headings.

The error it throws is so long so here I paste the first section of it:

```
[NbConvertApp] Using existing profile dir: 'C:\\Users\\Me\\.ipython\\profile_default'
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook headers.ipynb to latex
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in headers_files\
[NbConvertApp] Loaded template article.tplx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda 3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_win32.py", line 76, in _find_cmd
from win32api import SearchPath
ImportError: No module named 'win32api'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda 3\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in <module> sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda 3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
...
```

Comment: Please state the question again in one sentence this would make it clearer what you are asking. Right now one needs to extract the information.

Comment: Ooh sorry, it's my first post lol. The problem is "how can I convert ipynb files to PDF if they have headings?" because I can't make it with the normal command.

Comment: No problem. You should avoid stuff like "any clue" or so at the end of the question and summarize the question in one line if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I hope somebody knows how to solve it, becuase it's draving me crazy :(

Comment: I'm not at all proficient in ipython but you might be interested in this: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5877. Especially the last post.

Comment: That's not actually solving my problem as I'm supposed to work it out from the command line, and my headings don't have numbering. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY I got it!

First of all, when analysing the Error Code, we can see that the program asks us for the 'win32api'. To solve this problem, one must open the Anaconda Command Prompt **as administrator** and write:

```
conda install pywin32
```

With this, we will fix the missing package. But it doesn't end here, because if we try it again, a longer error will pop up so we also need to install the *pandoc* pack. In order to do this, we must close the command prompt and download it from [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) and run it with everything else closed.

Then, one can run smoothly the nbconvert command for everything, yay! :D

So remember, before using nbconvert, be sure that you have:

1. pywin32
2. pandoc